# Copy Paste Range using LastRow

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

I have a question on how to copy a formula from a certain specified range to a specified FirstRow to LastRow if from `A7` onward until LastRow the rows have data.

If from `A7` until LastRow has Data, the formula from `H6:J6` should be pasted as formula from `H7:J7` until LastRow.

Now the problem is if from `A7` onward the rows are empty, it will copy the formula in `H5:J5`. Is there a code I can use so that if `A7` onward is empty that no formula is copied at all? Perhaps Define the FirstRow as fixed or something.

```
Sub CopyFormulaIF()

Dim myLastRow As Long
Dim myCol As Long
Dim WB As Workbook
Dim WS As Worksheet

Set WB = ThisWorkbook
Set WS = WB.Sheets("Tabelle1")

'Screen update in 0 seconds
Application.ScreenUpdating = 0

With WS
    myLastRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
End With

For myCol = 8 To 10                                              
    Cells(6, myCol).Copy                                        
    Range(Cells(7, myCol), Cells(myLastRow, myCol)).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlFormulas 
Application.CutCopyMode = False                             
Next myCol

End Sub
```

Sample:
[image]

Thanks a lot guys

Comment: Did you check if myLastRow returns the correct value? I see from the sample that A2, A3 and A6 are empty, so your myLastRow value is probably 3 cells short.

Comment: @YowE3K Thanks for explaining!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could do this

```
Option Explicit

Sub CopyFormulaIF()
    Dim myLastRow As Long
    Dim myCol As Long

    'Screen update in 0 seconds Application.ScreenUpdating = 0

    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Tabelle1")
        myLastRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

        If myLastRow < 7 Then Exit Sub

        For myCol = 8 To 10
            .Range(.Cells(7, myCol), .Cells(myLastRow, myCol)).FormulaR1C1 = .Cells(6, myCol).FormulaR1C1
        Next
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: @Denny, did you get through it?

Comment: Hi user3598756, yes the code above works perfectly. Thanks a lot for your help. :-)